# Styled Expander Control Template and not able to view Expanded Content on Click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate, expander

I am just styling the Expander Control in WPF. I have defined only the styles in `Expander Control Template`, but I am not able to view the content of expander when I click on it. 
I guess I have to define the expander trigers also ? but I don't know which triger and how to define it. 
Also why I have to define triggers when I am just styling the expander.

```
<Window x:Class="ExpanderControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Expander">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="0" Name="contentRow"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <!--Expander Header-->
                            <Border Background="AliceBlue"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    >
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" ContentSource="Header"
                                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                      Margin="5"
                                                      ></ContentPresenter>
                                    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1">
                                        <TextBlock>x</TextBlock>
                                    </ToggleButton>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>

                            <!--Expander Content-->
                            <Border Background="Aqua" Grid.Row="1">
                                <ContentPresenter  Grid.Row="1"></ContentPresenter>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>


                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Expander Header="Expander" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="205,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <Menu>
                    <MenuItem Header="hi"></MenuItem>
                </Menu>

            </Grid>
        </Expander>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You set `Height="0"` on the content row. There is nothing bound to `IsChecked` of the `ToggleButton` to do something when it's open/closed. Basically it does nothing. Check how [Expander Styles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms753296(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @dkozl I have seen that, but I am not able to grasp how to do that? Also I want to the bound  `IsCheck` to the whole expander not only `ToogleButton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there is no action linked to `ToggleButton`. You need to utilize `Expander.IsExpanded` property by binding it

1. To `ToggleButton.IsChecked`
2. To `Border.Visibility` via `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` (custom or built in)
3. Set content row height to `Auto`

This way changing `ToggleButton.IsChecked` will change `Expander.IsExpanded` which in turn will affect visibility of content `Border`. It will also work when you change `IsExpanded` property from outside.

This is working XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
   <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
               <Grid>
                  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" Name="contentRow"/>
                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <!--Expander Header-->
                  <Border Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Row="0">
                     <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" />
                        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" Content="x" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsExpanded}"/>
                     </Grid>
                  </Border>
                  <!--Expander Content-->
                  <Border Background="Aqua" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsExpanded, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                     <ContentPresenter/>
                  </Border>
               </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**EDIT**

If you want whole header to be able to expand/collapse your `Expander` you need to bring `ContentPresenter` for `Header` into `Content` of `ToggleButton`. In your case basically bring header `Grid` into `ToggleButton.Content`

```
<!--Expander Header-->
<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsExpanded}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" />
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="x" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
   </Grid>
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: `ToggleButton` is working fine now, but the `TextBlock` is not working, I tried that MSDN example also, In that example only `ToogleButton` is working but in wpf default control without any custom control template the whole expander block along with `header` and `toggle button `expands on click

Comment: Which `TextBlock` is not working? Do you want whole header to be able to expand/collapse your `Expander`?

Comment: Then bring `ContentPresenter` for header into `ToggleButton`'s content. See my edit